# su: cannot set user id: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, users, su

I'm trying to create a new user and enter into it, under my Linux SUSE SLSE12 machine. I'm root on that machine. The set of commands:

```
> whoami
root
> useradd -u 123456 new_user
> id new_user
uid=123456(new_user) gid=100(users)
> su new_user
su: cannot set user id: Invalid argument
```

What is the problem with `su`? Why can't I switch to `new_user`? I tried `su - new_user` as well and got the same result. I also set a password to `new_user` using the `passwd` command but it still didn't work. How to solve it?

Comment: I've never seen that before. Maybe they have some sort of strict checking against UID_MAX from `/etc/login.defs`? Usually you just get a warning. I've never used SUSE though.

Comment: Aren't some implementations of su still relying on a short int representation of the user id ? (=> whatever >= 65535 would give unpredictable results)

Comment: And of course, did you ensure new_user gets a valid home dir ?

Comment: If it were a recent kernel I would check the system is not actually running within a container and user namespace with `cat /proc/$$/uid_map`. What's the output of this command?

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a more elaborate form of comment.

`su` produces this error message whet `setuid` fails:

```
static void
change_identity (const struct passwd *pw)
{
#ifdef HAVE_INITGROUPS
  errno = 0;
  if (initgroups (pw->pw_name, pw->pw_gid) == -1)
    error (EXIT_CANCELED, errno, _("cannot set groups"));
  endgrent ();
#endif
  if (setgid (pw->pw_gid))
    error (EXIT_CANCELED, errno, _("cannot set group id"));
  if (setuid (pw->pw_uid))
    error (EXIT_CANCELED, errno, _("cannot set user id"));
}
```

According to `man 3 setuid`:

> The setuid() function shall fail, return -1, and set errno to the corresponding value if one or more of the following are true:

> EINVAL
> The value of the uid argument is invalid and not supported by the implementation.

> EPERM
> The process does not have appropriate privileges and uid does not match the real user ID or the saved set-user-ID.

In this case, it is `EINVAL` (invalid argument)

As @MC68020 suggested that there might still be a limit of 65535, it might be  worth trying a lower UID. But the problem is strange.

Comment: +1, not to tell, if going through seccomp, its hardcoded limitation of uid < 65535